# Deploy a Sharded Cluster using Configuration File ERROR

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing

I'm following the MongoDB Manual for Deploy a Sharded Cluster. I create a conf file like this

```
sharding:
  clusterRole: configsvr
replication:
  replSetName: TwitterConfigServer
net:
  port: 27218
  bindIp: localhost,0.0.0.0
```

and run it with `mongod --config MongoDB/cluster_mongod_twitter_config_server.conf`
and I get this ERROR:

```
_config_server.conf","net":{"bindIp":"localhost,0.0.0.0","port":27218},"replication":{"replSetName":"TwitterConfigServer"},"sharding":{"clusterRole":"configsvr"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-20T16:25:12.302+02:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/configdb not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-20T16:25:12.302+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-20T16:25:12.302+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
```

So I specifing dbpath:  `mongod --config MongoDB/cluster_mongod_twitter_config_server.conf --dbpath MongoDB/cluster_mongod_twitter_config_server.conf`
and I get this:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-20T16:26:29.102+02:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"DBPathInUse: Unable to create/open the lock file: 

    MongoDB/cluster_mongod_twitter_config_server.conf/mongod.lock (Not a directory). Ensure the user executing mongod is the owner of the lock file and has the appropriate permissions. Also make sure that another mongod instance is not already running on the MongoDB/cluster_mongod_twitter_config_server.conf directory"}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2021-09-20T16:26:29.102+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2021-09-20T16:26:29.103+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
```

Please help me. I'm on Mac OS (M1 Processor).

Comment: File `MongoDB/cluster_mongod_twitter_config_server.conf` is **relative** to your current directory. Better use absolute path. I would not recommend to mix settings in config file and command line options. Better but **all** options into the config file and start mongod only with `--config` option

Comment: Of course, I try it before but not work

Comment: Parameter `--dbpath` defines the **folder** where data is stored. You provided the config file.

Comment: Oh thanks Man, finally!